# compare jTextField - java

Tags: java, string, swing, compare, jtextfield

It is possible compare the value (string) of JTextField? I have some blocks of code similar to the bellow, so my ideia is compare (!= or ==) this - `pn50.setText(play4b)` with, for example, `pn50.setText(play5b);`

I want avoid compare the string play5b or play4b, the reason is that pn50 is overwritten according to button pressed

```
        //card2
    ActionListener two = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (gr.getCounter1() < 1) {
                gr.setCounter1(gr.getCounter1() + 2);
                test1.setIcon(play1b);
                pn1.setText("Value of card: " + play2b);
                pn5.setText(play3b);
                pn50.setText(play4b);
                arraybtn[2].setText("no Card");
                arraybtn[2].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            } else {
                pn5.setText("Only one Card");
            }
        }
    };
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getText()` method will return the text of a `JTextBox`.  Use `.equals` or `.compareTo` to compare the Strings.

Comment: thanks, solved with, solved with pn50.getText().equals (pn80.getText())